# PHP XML limitation - $_POST limitation

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm trying to save a very large form in to a SQL database as XML.
The form is created from a XML file that the user uploads so the size of the form is unknown. Everything is working great unless the user uploads a file with more than 832 elements. The form is generated fine but the output from the form to XML just ends after the 832th element.

The form looks like this. This code is equal to one element in the XML file.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="115panel" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="115loop" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="115zone" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="115det" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="115type" value="OPT"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="115ir" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="115ok" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="115iok" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="115fr" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="115value" value="39"></td>
</tr>
```

$_POST[name] and $_POST[type] is set in the beginning of the form.

The PHP code to parse the form into XML looks like this

```
if($_POST['type'] == "PBS") {
    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $root = $xml->createElement("data");
    $root->setAttribute('name', $_POST['name']);
    $root->setAttribute('type', $_POST['type']);
    $xml->appendChild($root);
    $i = 0;
    $iP = 1;
    $iL = 1;
    $iD = 1;
    $run = 1;
    while($run == 1) {
        $search = $iP;
        $search .= $iL;
        $search .= $iD;
        if(isset($_POST[$search.'det'])) {
            $id = $xml->createElement("ID".$i);
            $root->appendChild($id);
            $central = $xml->createElement("panel");
            $centralText = $xml>createTextNode($_POST[$search.'panel']);
            $central->appendChild($centralText);
            $loop = $xml->createElement("loop");
            $loopText = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[$search.'loop']);
            $loop->appendChild($loopText);
            $zone = $xml->createElement("zone");
            $zoneText = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[$search.'zone']);
            $zone->appendChild($zoneText);
            $logicnumber = $xml->createElement("det");
            $logicnumberText = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[$search.'det']);
            $logicnumber->appendChild($logicnumberText);
            $type = $xml->createElement("type");
            $typeText = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[$search.'type']);
            $type->appendChild($typeText);
            $ir = $xml->createElement("ir");
            $irText = $xml->createTextNode(xIt($_POST[$search.'ir']));
            $ir->appendChild($irText);
            $ok = $xml->createElement("ok");
            $okText = $xml->createTextNode(xIt($_POST[$search.'ok']));
            $ok->appendChild($okText);
            $iok = $xml->createElement("iok");
            $iokText = $xml->createTextNode(xIt($_POST[$search.'iok']));
            $iok->appendChild($iokText);
            $fr = $xml->createElement("fr");
            $frText = $xml->createTextNode(xIt($_POST[$search.'fr']));
            $fr->appendChild($frText);
            $value = $xml->createElement("value");
            $valueText = $xml->createTextNode($_POST[$search.'value']);
            $value->appendChild($valueText);
            $id->appendChild($central);
            $id->appendChild($loop);
            $id->appendChild($zone);
            $id->appendChild($logicnumber);
            $id->appendChild($type);
            $id->appendChild($ir);
            $id->appendChild($ok);
            $id->appendChild($iok);
            $id->appendChild($fr);
            $id->appendChild($value);
            $i++;
        }
        $iD++;
        if($iD >= 250){
            $iD = 1;
            $iL++;
        }
        if($iL >= 9){
            $iL = 1;
            $iP++;
        }
        if($iP >= 10){
            $iP = 1;
            $run = 0;
        }
    }
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO kl_sks (customerID, user, date, data, status)
        VALUES ('".addslashes($_POST['name'])."', '".$_SESSION[sesUser]."', '".time()."', '".$xml->saveXML()."', '1')");
}
```

The code are looped through 250*8*9 times. A total of 18000 times, but the output stops at 832.

Here are an example of the output shorted down to the last one.

```
  <ID831>
    <panel>1</panel>
    <loop>1</loop>
    <zone>42</zone>
    <det>13</det>
    <type>801PH</type>
    <ir>0</ir>
    <ok>0</ok>
    <iok>0</iok>
    <fr>0</fr>
    <value>5</value>
  </ID831>
  <ID832>
    <panel>1</panel>
    <loop>1</loop>
    <zone>42</zone>
    <det>14</det>
    <type>801PH</type>
    <ir>0</ir>
    <ok>0</ok>
    <iok>0</iok>
    <fr>0</fr>
    <value>8</value>
  </ID832>
<data>
```

This was a XML document with 1300 elements, so 468 elements is missing

This seems to be a problem regarding the `php_value max_input_vars 5000`in php.ini, wich I can't change. So the question is how do i combine all the values in a element to a single $_POST variable, easily?

Comment: Could be a matter of increasing the `max_execution_time` flag in your php.ini

Comment: I'dont know if i can do that. The server is hosted by one.com.

Comment: You could try. I'm not familiar with one.com, so I won't be of any help there.

Comment: Do users actually upload XML files? Or do users enter form fields that this code renders to create XML file? If the former, why not parse uploaded temp file on server to PHP string and pass string into database?

Comment: I can't edit php.ini but i tried to make a .htaccess file and set `<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 1000
</IfModule>` with no luck. But i don't get a php error. Wouldn't I do that if its a timeout?

Comment: @Parfait Users upload a XML file witch is displayed in a form so the user can check checkboxes and change data if needed. But there is nothing wrong with the data input to the php, only the output.

Comment: Almost certainly running out of either memory or execution time (probably memory). You can increase the limits for both in the php.ini or .htaccess files. However, you would be better off rewriting your code to reduce the memory overhead.

Comment: I just can't see how it can be a memory issue. Were are talking a 1MB xml file. Actually the parsed file are like half the size of the one the user would upload! And what should i change to reduce memory consumption?

Comment: Can you post the html/php form code so we can see the origins of these `$_POST` variables?

Comment: I think i have found the answer. I ran the `phpinfo();` and found this line `php_value max_input_vars 5000` witch is odd cause I got 8073 variables out of it. I wrote to one.com's support and they will not change it. So i guess I have to combine some of the values somehow and then parse them. A lot of coding i'd rather be without.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to recreate the XML after form submission but use what user uploaded. The PHP form must contain a variable of the XML content used to display to webpage. You can use this large string in append query without looping and creating DOM document from scratch.

Comment: Okay I updated the question so take a look. I think I have to explain what this code is for. This system is for generating and organizing documentation for Firealarm-system. The user uploads 3 files. The 1. file is a XML file containing the structure of the Firealarm-system. The 2. file is a txt document containing the analog value of all the fire-sensors in the system. The 3. file is a txt document containing a list of all the fire-sensors that have been tested. These 3 files are then showed in a form where the user can make changes and stuff, which is 10 values per sensor. Then form to xml.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *alternative* approach that hopefully resolves memory leakage or variable limit. No longer does it involve running `while` looping but iterates through the `$_POST` associative array.

Also I condensed your XML code, removing the `CreateTextNode` object:

```
if($_POST['type'] == "PBS") {
  $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
  $root = $xml->createElement("data");
  $root->setAttribute('name', $_POST['name']);
  $root->setAttribute('type', $_POST['type']);
  $dom->appendChild($root);

  $i = 1;
  $panel = $loop = $zone = $det = $type = $it = $ok = $iok = $fr = $value = "";

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $item){

    if (strpos('panel', $key) !== FALSE) { $panel = $item; } 
    if (strpos('loop', $key) !== FALSE) { $loop = $item; } 
    if (strpos('zone', $key) !== FALSE) { $zone = $item; } 
    if (strpos('det', $key) !== FALSE) { $det = $item; } 
    if (strpos('type', $key) !== FALSE) { $type = $item; } 
    if (strpos('it', $key) !== FALSE) { $it = $item; } 
    if (strpos('ok', $key) !== FALSE) { $ok = $item; } 
    if (strpos('iok', $key) !== FALSE) { $iok = $item; } 
    if (strpos('fr', $key) !== FALSE) { $fr = $item; } 
    if (strpos('value', $key) !== FALSE) { $value = $item; } 

    if !empty($panel) && !empty($loop) && !empty($zone) 
      && !empty($det) && !empty($type) && !empty($it) && !empty($ok)
      && !empty($iok) && !empty($fr) && !empty($value) {

     $id = $dom->createElement("ID".$i);
     $root->appendChild($id);

     $panel = $dom->createElement("panel", $panel);
     $id->appendChild($panel);            
     $loop = $dom->createElement("loop", $loop);
     $id->appendChild($loop);            
     $zone = $dom->createElement("zone", $zone)
     $id->appendChild($zone);            
     $det = $dom->createElement("det", $det);
     $id->appendChild($det);            
     $type = $dom->createElement("type", $type);
     $id->appendChild($type);            
     $ir = $dom->createElement("ir", $ir);
     $id->appendChild($ir);            
     $ok = $dom->createElement("ok", $ok);
     $id->appendChild($ok);            
     $iok = $dom->createElement("iok", $iok);
     $id->appendChild($iok);                        
     $fr = $dom->createElement("fr", $fr)
     $id->appendChild($fr);            
     $value = $dom->createElement("value", $value);
     $id->appendChild($value);

     $i++;    
     $panel = $loop = $zone = $det = $type = $it = $ok = $iok = $fr = $value = "";    

     $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO kl_sks (customerID, user, date, data, status)
                     VALUES ('".addslashes($_POST['name'])."', '".$_SESSION[sesUser]."', 
                             '".time()."', '".$dom->saveXML()."', '1')");    
    }
  }
}
```

One caveat of this approach is if any of the ten node items are missing, it waits for next corresponding item to complete its 10 batch set, and hence misaligning rows (e.g., 115ok, 115iok, 116fr, 115value). Additional logic on the keys can help in this case.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out, with some small mods. I like the foreach loop, don't know why I didn't do it that way in the first place. However why would you remove the 'textNode' object an replace it with a 'Element' insted? It's just that I would have to change that in all the other code that handles the xml file afterwards.